# How to configure the htaccess to handle AJAX GET request?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, backbone.js

Backbone was running fine and then I accidentally deleted my `.htaccess` file.

I can access my database fine using a GET request directly from the URL, but when I go in via Backbone GET using ajax, no go.

What could the relation possible be?

Here is relevant PHP:

```
private function startDB()
{
    try
    {
        $this->db_one = new PDO( 'mysql:dbname=foo;host=localhost', 'foo_user', 'foo_pass' );
        // echo "working";
    }
    catch( PDOException $pdoError )
    {
        echo 'PDO connection failed: <br> ' . $pdoError->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to Backbone. You need to configure your `.htaccess` file back to what it was, but since you've given almost no information on your setup, we can't help. **What do you mean by `no go`?** Is there an error? Is there a log of the request? Are you using CORS? Do you see the same URL from the network tab in the Chrome dev tools?

Comment: To update my shared hosting provider sais the mistake is on their end 500 internal server error.   And I was wrong I can't connect via normal GET or ajax GET ... are there any special configurations that need to be setup ... I have troubleshot in the code all that I can

Comment: _"are there any special configurations that need to be setup"_ we can't guess! You're not providing any useful information in order to receive help.